# Host system hangs when starting any virtual machine in Hyper-V

Tags: windows-8.1, virtualization, hyper-v

This is a problem that I noticed several times now and I can't find any answer to this, so I hope that anyone of you can help me out.
Today I wanted to start a virtual machine in Hyper-V running on a Windows 8.1 Pro host machine.
In fact everytime I try to start a virtual machine with Hyper-V, my host system suddenly hangs and has to be shutdown by pressing the power off button.
It seems that this problem occurs regardless of the virtual machine's operating system, the type of the vm or any other vm settings.
After the host machine started to hang I just can power it off. If I turn it on again there are two options that I noticed:

1. The host's operating system still works but it is very slow and unresponsive
2. About 1 min. after booting the host machine it starts to hang again.

The only solution to this problem is to reinstall the whole operating system.

Does anyone of you know about this problem or can give me further advice what to do / to look for to solve this problem? This is just a problem with Hyper-V because with other software like Virtualbox etc. this problem does not occur.

Edit:
My specs:
OS: Windows 8.1 Pro 64 bit
CPU: AMD FX-6300 (Virtualization enabled in BIOS)
RAM: 8GB
I know that Hyper-V worked once some time ago but I don't know what changed. No hardware changes, no software changes except for some reinstallations of the OS.

Comment: I would think that this would be a hardware problem, CPU maybe? It's really hard to tell without more information.

Comment: 1. Do you have both Hyper-V and VirtualBox installed on the host machine? 2. if you ported the VM from Virtualbox, did you remove the guest tools? 3. Without running the VM, what is the resource usage on your host machine?

Comment: 1. No only Hyper-V, 2. VM wasn't ported, 3. Quite normal, about 1-5% CPU, 1.5GB RAM, no suspicious IO activity.